# Display WordPress page content with shortcode and show embedded shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using a Custom Post Type to display banners on my site.
The content could be text, images and also shortcodes (e.g. a button shortcode).

If I display the content with my shortcode, everything looks finde. Except of shortcodes inside the banner itself.

Is there any way to render that shortcode?

Here's my shordcode:

```
// [banner id="" class=""]
function shortcode_banner( $atts, $content ){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    => '',
        'class' => '',
    ), $atts));

    $banner_id  = $id;
    $content    = get_post_field('post_content', $banner_id);

        return '<div class="'.$class.'">'.wpautop($content).'</div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'banner', 'shortcode_banner' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
// [banner id="" class=""]
function shortcode_banner( $atts, $content ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => '',
        'class' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    $banner_id = $id;
    $content   = get_post_field( 'post_content', $banner_id );

    return '<div class="'.$class.'">'.wpautop( do_shortcode( $content ) ).'</div>';
}
```

or if you expect to have recursive shortcodes:

```
function recursively_do_shortcode( $content ) {
    $content2 = $content;
    do{
       $content = $content2;
       $content2 = do_shortcode( $content );
    } while( $content2 !== $content ); // presumably you can test if shortcodes exist in content as well
    return $content2;
}

// [banner id="" class=""]
function shortcode_banner( $atts, $content ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => '',
        'class' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    $banner_id = $id;
    $content   = get_post_field( 'post_content', $banner_id );

    return '<div class="'.$class.'">'.wpautop( recursively_do_shortcode( $content ) ).'</div>';
}
```

Reference: [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

Comment: @Cray  did you add `add_shortcode( 'banner', 'shortcode_banner' );`? I did not include it in the answer but you should do that

Comment: My fault. Now it works perfect, thanks! One question: what do you understand by "recursive shortcodes"

Comment: @Cray, I mean shortcodes which when rendered return other shortcodes which in turn have to be rendered and so on untill no other shortcode is returned